# Why does `Array.length`, `Function.length`, `String.length`, etc return 1?

Tags: javascript

While teaching my JavaScript class yesterday, my students and I came across some interesting functionality that I thought might be worth capturing in a question and the answer I've come to.

Typing `Array.length` in the JS console in chrome returns `1`.

Likewise, `Function.length` returns `1`. This is important because:

> Every function in JavaScript is actually a Function object. [(MDN JS Ref: Function)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

Thus, `Object.length` and likely all other native objects will and should return `1` as the value of the `length` property.

So, finally *why* is this behavior occurring?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Function.length` itself is the answer:

> Specifies the number of arguments expected by the function. [MDN JS Ref: Function.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length)

When we write `Function.length` we are asking the `Function` constructor to tell us the number of formal, named parameters ("optional" - i.e. non-formal - parameters are accessed via the `arguments` property in the function body). Because the `Function` constructor expects exactly 1 formal named parameter, the result is `1`:

```
new Function ([arg1[, arg2[, ... argN]],] functionBody)
```

`functionBody` is the single formal named parameter. Therefore `Function.length` is `1`.

Comment: This is pretty much right (+1), but I'd add that `Function.length` gets the number of *formal, named parameters*, and "optional" (i.e. non-formal) parameters are accessed via the `arguments` variable in the function body.

Comment: To further clarify, there is no necessary correspondence between formal/non-formal parameters and "required"/"optional" arguments. The former is a matter of function definition; the latter is a question of API specification.

Comment: @apsillers You're absolutely right. I've added that edit. Thanks for the heads up.